# How to Print Selection without the cell background color ( black and white print ) VB

Tags: vba, excel

How to change this line of code in order to not select the cell fill color or somehow PrintOut the selection in black and white, while keeping the fill color on the page.

```
Range("H8:K10" & "," & "A" & firstRow & ":G" & lastRow).PrintOut
```

Comment: Why not add that in a [`BeforePrint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-beforeprint-event-excel) event that removes the cell color, and adds back in after printing? AFAIK you can't do what you're trying by editing that single line.

Comment: see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-blackandwhite-property-excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.
`Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.BlackAndWhite = True`

Comment: It's been awhile so I don't remember the color fill, but I remember using it and it printed in black and white

Comment: According to Microsoft, it will print in black or white. Here's the link to the site [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-blackandwhite-property-excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-blackandwhite-property-excel)